# How many terms can you remove from the power series $f(x)$ and still have an extendable function?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I was watching [this video](https://youtu.be/krtf-v19TJg) and I had a question. The video explains how

$f(z) = 1 + z + z^2 + \cdots$

has an analytic continuation (that being $\frac{1}{1-z}$) but the function with just the powers of 2,

$g(z) = z^1 + z^2 + z^4 + z^8 +\cdots$

does not have one. My question is, how many powers can be removed from $f(z)$ before the function no longer has an analytic continuation (or an extension)

Comment: I guess $f(x)-g(x)$ doesn't

Comment: Then$\sum z^{n!}$

Comment: Obviously you must remove infinitely many (answering your question in the body, which is the opposite of the one in the title — grrr). But that criterion alone is not sufficient, as in some cases it will be continuable (e.g., $\sum z^{2n}$) and in others it will not.